# Ошибка при загрузке данных с xml

Tags: jquery, ajax

Выдает ошибку при загрузке. В чем проблема? Если ошибка в коде, то напишите как правильно. Пробовал отсылать запрос на свой домен, все равно ошибка

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxGetXML()
});

function ajaxGetXML(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://citforum.ck.ua/internet/xmlxslt/Examples/Xsl/ex01.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) { 
            alert($(data).find('tutorial').text())
        },
        // если произошла ошибка при получении файла
        error: function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: _"Выдает ошибку"_ -- что в message этой ошибки?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ajaxGetXML() });` можно заменить на `$(ajaxGetXML);`

Comment: а в `$(xml)` -- xml это что?

Comment: Это называется `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Нельзя такой запрос отослать на другой домен. Политика безопасности.... Если конечно тот самый сервер не принадлежит вам и вы сами можете настроить кому отдавать xml а кому нет

Comment: Что за ошибка? Используйте F12

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(%D0%AE%D1…BB%D1%8B%20.html/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0/ex01.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код вполне исправный.
Проблема в том, что `ajax` не работает на локальном сайте

Comment: Можно сделать чтобы работал в настройках или аргументах запуска браузера.